# A general formula to calculate sum of product of all combinations of size r from given n numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a quesion -
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/ode-to-code-finals/challenges/pingu-and-pinglings

The question basically asks to generate all combinations of size k and sum up the product of numbers of all combinations..Is there a general formula to calculate the same,as it is quite tough to generate all the possible combinations and operate on them..
For example for n=3(no of elements) and k=2
and the given 3 numbers are 4 2 1,then the answer will be 14 as
For k=2 the combinations are {4,2},{4,1},{2,1} so answer is (4×2)+(4×1)+(2×1)=8+4+2=14.
I hope i am clear in asking my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers in your set are $a_1,\dots,a_n$, then your sum is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the product $\prod_i (1+a_ix)$. If there's a relationship between the $a_i$'s, then you might be able to simplify the product and then extract the coefficient of $x^k$. Otherwise, I doubt there's much simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about a more efficient algorithm than merely summing $\displaystyle{n\choose2}=\dfrac{n(n-1)}2$ products ? If so, then you can sum only *n* products, namely $S_2=\dfrac12\cdot\displaystyle\sum_1^na_k(S_1-a_k),$ where $S_1=\displaystyle\sum_1^na_k.$

Comment: and what about S3,S4,S5  and say Sn?

Comment: @user3366497: $S_3$ will depend upon $S_2$, just like $S_2$ is dependent upon $S_1$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a general case for size 2:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^na_ia_j=\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2}{2}$$